# Mbox 1 as an audio interface into Live 8 intro is only causing a static hiss

Tags: audio-recording, mac, ableton-live

I am running Ableton live 8 intro on an Imac running OS X snow leopard. My audio interface is an original Mbox, when i am recording audio and arm a track, all i get is static on the track and the levels are maxing out. I have installed it in live as per the tutorials and cant see what i am doing wrong. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does it still happen when there is nothing plugged into the inputs on the Mbox?

Comment: Yea could easily be cables going into mbox

Answer (score 1):

Everything is a matter of drivers. Basically, the drivers must be installed with a ProTools 8.0.1 or less, and they WON'T WORK ON A X64 OS !
If you use the regular Digidesign drivers, they won't work on a 64-bits OS. The best way to make the MBOX work on 64-Bits OS is to download (they cost $60, but better take a TORRENT file) the PloyTec USB ASIO Drivers for MBOX (You also have to install ASIO4ALL). Use THE 2.8.40 version, since the 2.8.45 is still buggy. Good luck !